# latex tokens reader breaks on \iffalse

Tags: macros

everyone,
I've found a very strange behavior of latex `\iffalse` with `\newcommand\NAT@parse...` inside of it (`\NAT@parse` taken directly from natbib). If I add that macro in style, then latex breaks with `"! Too many }'s."`

for example I'll create a style **temp.sty**:

```
\iffalse
  \newcommand\NAT@parse[1]{%
    \begingroup
     \let\protect=\@unexpandable@protect
     \let~\relax
     \let\active@prefix=\@gobble
     \edef\NAT@temp{\csname b@#1\@extra@b@citeb\endcsname}%
     \aftergroup\NAT@split
     \expandafter
    \endgroup
    \NAT@temp{}{}{}{}{}@@%
    \expandafter\NAT@parse@date\NAT@date??????@@%
    \ifciteindex\NAT@index\fi
  }%
\fi

\endinput
```

And load it in **sample.tex**:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{temp}
\begin{document}
nothing
\end{document}
```

`\iffalse` should ignore everything till `\fi`, but it breaks.
Can somebody explain why it happens?

Comment: Because `\ifciteindex` is not yet defined as a conditional when the code is processed, so TeX skips over it and uses the next `\fi` to match `\iffalse`. This leaves `}\fi` outside any conditional.

Comment: @egreg Looks like an answer to me!

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's a great answer. Long time a go I had such an issue. And I'll remember that it was because of undefined `\if`. Now I didn't noticed that.

Comment: I don't know "latex tokens reader", I know only "TeX tokens reader". So the title of this thread may make confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just naming a token `\ifciteindex` doesn't make it into a conditional. Only

```
\let\ifciteindex\iftrue
```

or

```
\let\ifciteindex\iffalse
```

guarantees this.

So in your code, `\ifciteindex` is skipped over as any other non conditional token and the immediately following `\fi` matches the initial `\iffalse`. This leaves an unbalanced `}` and also a `\fi`.

Fix. Add

```
\@ifundefined{ifciteindex}
  {\expandafter\let\csname ifciteindex\expandafter\endcsname\csname iffalse\endcsname}
  {}
```

before the first `\iffalse`.

Comment: `\@ifundefined{ifciteindex}
  {\newif\ifciteindex}
  {}` and then `\if....\ifciteindex..\fi...\fi`

Comment: @Linuxss This will break if `\ifciteindex` *is* defined as a conditional (because you load `natbib` before `temp`, for instance). `;-)`

Comment: I can't argue. I agree

Answer (score 1):

This is typical that a macro code has not blanced `\if...\fi`, so the surrounding such macro code by `\iffalse...\fi` is bad idea. Much better is to use `\endinput` before skipped macro code or simply to use `\iffalse...\fi` in main document, i. e.

```
\iffalse \usepackage{temp}\fi
```

or more simple:

```
%\usepackage{temp}
```